# Where can I post job listings or browse through resumes?

Tags: hiring, jobs, human-resources

[Hypothetically] I'm at a smaller company and looking for a place to get the word out about our available openings.  Alternately, I'm looking for a place to browse through resumes of people looking for jobs.  What are some services I can use to find the people I need?

**Answer Format**

- One URL per answer
- Costs (if applicable)
- Specializations (if any)
- Experiences using the service

Answer (score 12):

### [Gamasutra Jobs](http://www.gamasutra.com/jobs/)

This is the canonical place to go if you want to hire a game developer, or become one.

**Cost:**

Recruitment pricing on [this page](http://www.gamasutra.com/recruitment/). It appears job postings are free.

**Specialization:**

Game development. "The game industry leader in career resources"

Answer (score 5):

### [StackOverflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)

[FAQ here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq).

**Costs:**

- 1 year filing: $19 or free for students
- 30 day job listing: $350
- Hiring manager: test drive free, to view candidates and make contact subscriptions are $500 for one week, $1000 for one month, $3000 for 6 months, $5000 for one year
- 90 day money back guarantee if you are dissatisfied

**Specializations:** "professional software developers looking for great places to work" (developers who browse Stack Overflow)

I have no experiences using it, sorry.

Comment: -1, I searched for "game" and got a total of 15 answers.  3 of which might have been actual game programming jobs.  Doesn't seem to be a critical mass of "game development" jobs on this site.

Comment: @Tetrad, can I downvote that comment? :) Although this *is* a gamedev site, your *Question* didn't mention looking specifically for *game programmers*, nor did it mention requiring a *critical mass* of them. Even assuming you were looking to hire programmers to create *games*, it's a reasonable assumption that you were looking for *professional* programmers, and would/could train them in the specifics of your job. (I note that you once asked how to sort thru **zero-experience** candidates also :)

Comment: @Tetrad - having just criticized your comment - if you're hiring *Unity* developers (or C#/Python programmers), where can I send my resume to? :)

Comment: I would hope that it's obvious from the context of this site that I'm looking for places where game developers (not just programmers) would see them.

Answer (score 2):

Another place you can post job ads is the IGDA boards but they're usually local in nature. On the other hand there are usually freelancers there as well.

Answer (score 2):

Game Industry Grunts

http://gameindustrygrunts.com/

The idea of this site is that it is free for everyone, so non-rich companies, and rich companies that want post entry-level jobs can post there.

Comment: Weird, it looks like it's using the same software/theme as a similar game site, http://gamejobhunter.com/

Comment: Interesting, I did not knew this one...

Comment: I forgot pressing "enter" on comments submits them... Anyway, I know that game industry grunts was made by a Ubisoft employee (that is obviously fan of Warcraft... actually the logo previously was a Orc Grunt head)

Answer (score 1):

### [Game Job Hunter](http://gamejobhunter.com/)

**Cost:**

- Basic job ads - Free
- Spotlight job ads links on home page - $50/week
- Header banner ad, appears on all pages (728x90, jpg or gif) - $250/week
- Skyscraper ad, appears on all pages (120x600, jpg or gif) - $200/week

Answer (score 1):

## [Mobile Gaming Jobs](http://www.mobilegamingjobs.com)

**Costs**: 199 per job. Discounts on multiple jobs and longer terms.

**Specialization**: Focuses on mobile game development only and powers the job listings on several large developer focused sites.

Answer (score -2):

### [Microsoft Students 2 Business](http://www.microsoft.com/studentstobusiness/home/default.aspx)

([global site](http://www.microsoft.com/studentstobusiness/home/default.aspx), [USA site](http://s2b.experience.com/))

**Costs:** Free for students. Maybe free for recruiters?

**Specializations:** students in IT majors (computer science, information technology, etc.)

My only experience was to promote it to fellow students, as my school's Microsoft Student Partner. I personally found it to have a very limited selection of job openings.

Comment: could whoever down-voted this give an explanation?

Comment: Nothing game-specific. Useless to 70% of game developers (non-programmers), and poorly-targeted targeted for the remaining 30%.

Comment: I agree, I just posted it as an option. It might be worth keeping an eye on, especially in an area with a lot of game dev companies, but I don't even see it getting off the ground, despite the effort and money that Microsoft is probably throwing into it.